# Incorrect user input

Tags: c++

Trying to let only numbers be a vaild input for a quadratic equation solver. I used bool and broke my code and no matter the input it just gives me my error message even if it is a vaild input.

After the progarm ask you to confirm the coefficients are correct, even if you put Y you get the " Please input a number. Please try again". how do you fix this?
I added the bool becasue that what my teacher showed me to use for checking inputs, very new to c++ and coding. I just added the whole code, the HW was to update HW 5 to do a few things more. I broke it trying to check inputs, when adding bool.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string first, last;
    double a, b, c, x1, x2, discriminant, realpart, imaginarypart;
    char ch;
    cout << "Please enter First and Last name," << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "First Name= ";
    cin >> first;
    cout << "and" << endl;
    cout << "Last Name=";
    cin >> last;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << " Hello " << first << " " << last << " "
         << "welcome." << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    bool isCorrect{ true };
    do {
    start:
        isCorrect = true;
        cout << "Enter the coefficients of a: ";
        cin >> a;
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "Enter the coefficients of b: ";
        cin >> b;
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "Enter the coefficient of c: ";
        cin >> c;
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << " A = " << a;
        cout << " B = " << b;
        cout << " C = " << c << endl
             << endl;
        cout << " Confirm the coefficients value are correct or not (y/n): " << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
        cin >> ch;
        if (ch == 'n' || ch == 'N')
            goto start;
        cout << " " << endl;
        discriminant = b * b - 4.0 * a * c;
        if (cin.fail())
            ;
        {
            isCorrect = false;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(245, '\n');
            cout << " Please input a number. Please try again" << endl;
        }
    } while (!isCorrect);
    bool isExit(false);
    if (a == 0) {
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "Error message: a can not = zero (0) " << endl;
    }
    else if (discriminant > 0) {
        x1 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2.0 * a);
        x2 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2.0 * a);
        cout << "Roots are real and different." << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "x1 = " << x1 << endl;
        cout << "x2 =" << x2 << endl;
    }
    else if (discriminant == 0) {
        cout << "Roots are real and same." << endl;
        cout << " " << endl;
        x1 = -b / (2.0 * a);
        cout << "x1 = x2 ="
                " "
             << x1 << endl;
    }
    else {
        //cout << "Error message: No real solution exist." << endl; // Part 1 error code for no real solutions
        realpart = -b / (2.0 * a); //Code for part 2
        imaginarypart = sqrt(-discriminant) / (2.0 * a); // Code for part 2
        cout << "Roots are complex and different." << endl; // Code for part 2
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "x1 = " << realpart << "+" << imaginarypart << "i" << endl; // Code for part 2
        cout << "x2 = " << realpart << "-" << imaginarypart << "i" << endl; // Code for part 2
    }
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << " Would you like to solve another quadratic equation (y/n): " << endl;
    cin >> ch;
    if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
        goto start;
    else
        (ch == 'n' || ch == 'N');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What kind of numbers are allowed? Only natural numbers, or are real numbers also okay?

Comment: What is `bool isCorrect(true);` supposed to do? It also looks like the `do { ... } while` is outside a function. That will not compile. Also, stay away from `goto` - it makes everything messy. Please make a [mre]

Comment: `goto start` could simply be `continue` instead

Comment: `bool isCorrect(true);` You probably want `bool isCorrect {true};` or `bool isCorrect = true;`

Comment: Any number is allowed.

Comment: "Continue " will take me back to the start if the input was wrong and the user wanted to re-input the  number?

Comment: continue inside the loop will take you to the same place as goto but is a more accepted practice

Comment: There was a ; on if (cin.fail()) removing it fix my problem . Thank you for the input, Please add any other hints, errors, or bad habits you see. Thank you .